# Designing a roadmap

Tags: vector, software-recommendation, drawing

do you know any program to easily create a roadmap like that:

https://github.com/MoienTajik/AspNetCore-Developer-Roadmap/blob/master/aspnetcore-developer-roadmap-printable.png

Comment: Terminology may be an issue. If you search for "flowchart" software, you'll find lots.

Comment: https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "easily", and the skills you have. Easy is very subjective.

The exampple could have been generated using dedicated flowchart software, and the process could be semi-automated, since flowchart software is specifically designed for such purposes. As to which one has this particular look, it's anybody's guess. There's lots if you search.

However it could be done easily enough (if you have the skills) using almost any vector image editing software such as Illustrator, Inkscape, CorelDraw, Figma, etc - but it would be a manual process. You'd have to draw and position everything yourself. This would be entirely possible, and not exactly rocket science or anything so complex. However there is a learning curve using such software if you've never used anything like that before.

Once you have made the individual elements like the text boxes, icons, lines etc, you can just copy them and re-use them. It would be slow to start with, but once you have made all the elements, it would be easy enough to modify, duplicate, reposition, retype the text and so on.

A very quick example I made in a few minutes using Inkscape (which is free).

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LucidChart](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/) or [SmartSheet](https://www.smartsheet.com/). I prefer LucidChart as it's very simple to learn but extremely capable and has a ton of options. SmartSheet is more of a PM tool, but would still be able to help you.